# Polygon flickering when calling SetPoints on google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an android app using the google maps sdk (11.6.2). I'm drawing a polygon on the map and given a user's movement, the shape of the polygon changes. I'm changing the shape by calling `setPoints` instead of redrawing the polygon, but its fill color is still flickering. Even when applying the same exact points (a constant `ArrayList<LatLng>`) the fill color still flickers.

The following code demonstrates this case. The code shows a google map marker drag listener. `onMarkerStart` is called when a user picks up a certain marker - at this point I save a certain list of `LatLngs`. `onMarkerDrag()` is called whenever a user moves a marker after picking it up. To simplify, all `setPoints` are called with the same array of positions.

```
ArrayList<LatLng> points;
private GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener mMarkerDragListener = new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {

    // marker is picked up
    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
        points = getPolygonPoints();
        mPolygon.setPoints(points);
    }

    // marker is being dragged around
    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
        mPolygon.setPoints(points);
    }

    // marker is dropped
    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

    }
};
```

Even with this simplified code, the polygon filling flickers heavily when a marker is moved around.

Doing some research Iv'e found a similar resolved issue regarding circles [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35823299) but the latest correspondence there seems to indicate that the same issue still persists with polygons.

I was wondering whether I'm doing something wrong\missing something or perhaps there's some other creative solution here.

Comment: Please add source code (part with redrawing/moving) of your app.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko code added